# IE and special characters

Tags: internet-explorer, character, special-characters, ie8-compatibility-mode

I have a weird problem with special characters "åäö" and IE 9.

[image]

If I turn on compatibility mode it shows the characters in their correct form, however I don't want to force the comp. mode on the user. Why is this always a solution?

Comment: This sounds weird indeed. Please provide more information, preferably a minimal HTML document that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It looks like it had something to do with the characters encoding, even though I specified utf-8 as encoding. I pasted text from a doc. to the file itself in textmate and that whats made everything, however I don't know why this only appears in IE9 and none of the other browsers like: Chrome, FF, Safar...

Comment: can you upload the HTML document and post a URL (if it’s too large to be posted here).

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela

http://www.nicesprites.se/test/test.html

Comment: thanks, there is definitely something odd going on, though I see the problem differently – äåö all look different from other letters (like raised) in Standards Mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED**

This is a tricky issue with many factors, but the most important is probably that the text (at least on the demo page) contains å, ä, ö in two ways: directly as simple characters, and as decomposed. E.g., the “å” of “våld” consists of “a” followed by combining ring above (U+030A). Unifying this so that simple characters are used consistently should fix the issue.

However the demo page also uses font name `open-sans` instead of `open sans`, causing further problems, but I suppose this might be a typo in the demo, not on the real page.

Overrides original answer:

This seems to be a problem in the use of the Google font Open Sans. Probably IE uses it differently depending its mode (Quirks vs. Standard), because old versions of IE do not support the WOFF format.

The problem may disappear if you download the font and serve it from your own server. It has often happened that Google fonts don’t work when used from Google server but are OK when you manage them yourself.

Answer (score 0):

These are all swedish characters. Probably you should use HTML compatible characters to get rid of problem. Try with  this character instead:

```
&auml;
&aring;
&ouml;
```

This will show correctly in every browser

Comment: with utf-8 this shouldn't be a necessity?

Comment: but does it show correctly in this way in IE

Comment: That would remove the symptoms, not the problem, and it would be the source very messy.